# Contact sensor: 6 axis force/torque sensing

Tags: gazebo-sensor, contact

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

It would be nice to extend the contact sensing tutorial to show how to add up all contact forces on a body to get an aggregate JointWrench (3 forces and 3 torques). This would allow the contact sensor to simulate a six axis force/torque sensor on the foot or wrist.

Even if the DRCSIM robot does not have such a sensor, this simulated sensor would be useful for debugging.

Thanks,
Chris

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/559/contact-sensor:-6-axis-force/torque-sensing/) by [cga](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/66/cga/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 223 on 2012-12-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

See [example in drcsim](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/drcsim/src/8e072fa972a0e2cd0104a35de1ecf1870f5c6c01/plugins/ros/AtlasPlugin.cc?at=default#cl-387) for summing up contact forces.

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) on 2013-07-23**:
There is also a new force torque sensor in gazebo: https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/pull-request/557/sonar-and-force-torque-sensors

Answer (score 0):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

For you timing question:

I think you should also print out the names of the objects that are colliding. Multiple objects may collide, and in turn produce multiple contacts during a single step.

---

Originally posted by [nkoenig](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/5/nkoenig/) with karma: 7676 on 2013-01-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1